# Civilization V not installing locally?

Tags: installation, gaming

I bought Civilization V, but when I run setup.exe from the CD on my Windows XP machine it just has the following options:

- Play
- Reinstall (note: the game is NOT installed)
- Uninstall
- Exit

If I choose play, it always connects to Steam. On the box it says "one time connection to Steam necessary", but it does not even seem to be installing locally on my machine at all.

I want to be able to play the game without an internet connection. How can I install it locally?

Comment: “How can I install it locally?” - Use the license to add it to your Steam library, install the game, go offline within Steam and start the game.  Civ 5 was several disk (4+) if memory serves me right.  Be sure your using the correct disk.  Unfriendly responses will be ignored and flagged.

Comment: Steam is just a library, your game doesn't get installed on some cloud somewhere. From the [requirements listed on Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/8930/Sid_Meiers_Civilization_V/), Civilization V requires an OS minimum of Windows Vista SP2/ Windows 7 so Windows XP is likely not supported.

Comment: @MC10 Based on the description Steam seems to be working.

Comment: Useful question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10449/can-i-play-civ-5-without-having-steam-installed

Answer (score 1):

Most retail games actually try and download from steam instead of from the disc. You need to run the install from the command line and specify the drive letter of your optical drive:

`"C:\Program Files\Steam\Steam.exe" -install E:`

(check and adjust the path to the steam program and the drive letter to match your own configuration)

You may have to "uninstall/delete" games files if you aborted a download attempt, but you must be logged in at least once to steam to authorize the license.

Civ 5 is fairly old at this point, so expect Steam to want to download updates. After install, you can set the games preferences to "never update."

But you will still need a periodic internet connection to play games.

Full article about disc install:

https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5357-FSQM-0382

Further info regarding offline mode:

https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3160-agcb-2555